# syncfusion context sensitive menu

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

I am using the syncfusion grid control. To this I've added a context sensitive menu 
but the menu doesn't seem to disappear even after releasing the mouse

Any hints?

Comment: Have you gone on to syncfusion's support site? http://www.syncfusion.com/support/all

Answer (score 0):

By default, context menu bounded through the ContextMenu or the ContextMenuStrip API of GridControl, will get closed automatically once any of its items is clicked.

Are you using any custom control as dropdown part? If so, you can handle call either to hide the dropdown control or dispose it(ctrl.Dispose()) in the MouseUp event of menu item after performing respective menu operation.